# Failed to uninstall this node.js package globally because the installed location has been deleted

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I tried to remove this node.js package `ibkr-api` globally

```
$ npm uninstall -g ibkr-api
```

I got the following error.

```
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "..\..\..\Inv\Programming\node.js\ibkr-api" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\young\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-21T06_40_48_468Z-debug.log
```

The contents of `2019-04-21T06_40_48_468Z-debug.log` is pasted here;
https://pastebin.com/raw/GNDP8g46

It seems the location where the package was installed has been deleted.

When I run the command;

```
$ npm list -g -depth=0
```

the node.js package is listed.

How do I uninstall this node.js package? This error is preventing me from updating and installing new node.js packages globally.

I am using Windows 10 64-bit and node.js v11.14.0

Comment: error says there's no `package.json` in your global path, where is your global `node_modules`?

Comment: The error says no package.json in the location of the node.js package that I am trying to remove. This folder has been accidentally removed by me while doing clean up.

Comment: create a `package.json` file in the same folder where `node_modules` previously exist, then run npm install --save <package name> and try the uninstall again

Comment: Thank you very much for your tip. The problem is solved. I posted an answer based on your tip. All credit goes to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question.

Based on the comments from fellow stack overflow user naga - elixir - jar, I managed to fix the problem. All credit goes to him.

Reinstall the node.js package at the exact same location where the log file says there is a missing `package.json`.

Now, uninstall the node.js package.

```
$ npm uninstall -g ibkr-api
```

The package was successfully removed.